# ASP.NET Webapplication avoid page reload for culture language change

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, resources

I'm trying to make a multilanguage ASP.NET web Application. At the beginning of the Application I'm setting up cookies and after that I'm calling InitializeCulture() to initiate the culture. The data for the page is stored in global resources and gets written in the aspx file like this: `<%$ Resources:Main,lang %>`

It is actually working but there is still a problem: After a click on a languagechange button the coockie and the culture changes but not the content of the page. I always have to reload the whole page to get the content of the right `global.resx`.

In PageLoad im calling this:

```
            setLanguageCookie(); //<- TO SET A COOKIE IF NULL
            InitializeCulture();
```

InitializeCulture() looks like this:

```
        string sprache = "en-US";

        if (Request.Cookies["sprache"] != null)
        { 
            sprache = Request.Cookies["sprache"].Value;
        }

        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture =
          CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(sprache);

        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture =
          CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(sprache);
```

There are 3 Language buttons. Their code behind look like this:

```
protected void lang_en_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Request.Cookies["sprache"] = "en-US";
            Session["Language"] = "en";
        }
```

Can someone give me a hint where I am mistaking? O is there even a better way to do that??

Comment: try this http://www.codeproject.com/articles/18753/developing-an-asp-net-page-with-masterpage-and-loc

Comment: try this, move `setLanguageCookie(); InitializeCulture();` this to your page_init method.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the following link it will show you how to retrieve resource file contents programmatically http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227982.aspx but it will be only useful if you have limited number of controls intialised from the resource files.

Answer (score 0):

Your lang_en_Click event is handled after the page load, so you have to call the set you CurrentTread.CurrentCulture again:

```
protected void lang_en_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     Request.Cookies["sprache"] = "en-US";     
     Session["Language"] = "en";         
     Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture =   CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US");   
     Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US");     
}
```

And you have to check if you do not set any language string before the lang_en_Click is handled. Normally I would set the right Culture info on the Pre_Render of your page. However if you have and manual handling of strings earlier that can lead to problems.

Answer (score 0):

InitializeCulture() is called before Click event in page cycle - so you are setting cookies too late. If you want to get the controls' values, you can read them from **Request.Form**, inside the InitializeCulture() method.

For example, if you use dropdownlist called mydropdown for changing the language, you can get its value from Request.Form["mydropdown"]. Or, in the example you've set (with a button for each language), you could set the language value inside a hidden field (on client) and then read its value from Form object.